# Form to JSON conversion not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I am trying to convert a filled in form in the HTML to a JSON request that can then be send to the server over HTTP POST. Although the form is filled, all that i see in the JSON request is an empty JSON array..

JS Snippet is given below

```
$("#submitSurveyBtn").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = JSON.stringify($("#surveyForm").serializeArray());
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/friends",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json"
    }).then(function (res) {
        console.log(res)
    });
});
```

HTML snippet is given below

```
<form id="surveyForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nameInput">Name(Required)</label>
                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput" placeholder="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imgInput">Link to Photo Image (Required)</label>
                <input id="imgURL" type="text" class="form-control" id="imgInput" placeholder="http://...">
            </div>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/rajdhandus/pen/pKWLzR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form HTML:

```
<input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput" placeholder="name">
....
<input id="imgURL" type="text" class="form-control" id="imgInput" placeholder="http://...">
```

You don't have name of your input so it can not be serialised as it is invalid

change to:

```
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput" placeholder="name">
...
<input id="imgURL" name="imgURL" type="text" class="form-control" id="imgInput" placeholder="http://...">
```

That's the main problem you have!

I would prefer to use the following construction, but it's up to you:

```
$("#surveyForm").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).serialize();  
    // ...
});
```

Comment: `data: formData` ... formData for `$.ajax` accepts different kind of data it could be object `{param1: vaue1, param2: value2}` but it could be url formatted string. Give it a try.

Comment: Of course `$.ajax` produces a HTTP call and sends form inputs values as HTTP arguments i.e. `name=xxx`, imgURL=xxx` and so on, not as JSON. That's the usual practice. If you prefer to send data as JSON string, of course you could do it in many ways, but after that in Backend you should  decode it to an Object, which is useless, in case you do not encrypt you data sent to Backend, as the case shows. So that's why I told I would do that.